# Is there a way to typedef this?

Tags: c++, typedef

Simplified version of the code:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        class Bar {
            // ...
        };
        typedef std::map<int, Bar> mapType;
        mapType _map;
    public:
        void method(mapType::iterator it);
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
void Foo::method(mapType::iterator it) {
    // ...
    notMethod(it);
}

void notMethod(mapType::iterator it) {
    // ...
}
```

Unsurprisingly, I get the error `'mapType' is not a class or namespace name` in VS2008 at `notMethod`'s definition. Is there any (elegant) way that I can avoid having to type out `std::map<int, Bar>` everywere in `notMethod`'s definition without turning `notMethod` into a method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use

```
void notMethod(Foo::mapType::iterator it) {
    // ...
}
```

and put the typedef in the public section of `Foo`'s class declaration.

Edit:

If you want to avoid this, you can

1. make `notMethod` a friend (as suggested by DanDan),
2. use sbi's template solution, or
3. make `notMethod` a private static member function of `Foo` (which generates exactly the same code as if it was a free non-member function).

Which solution is the most appropriate really depends on what `notMethod` does.

If `notMethod` uses `Bar` and `Bar` really only makes sense in the context of `Foo`'s internal implementation, I would make `notMethod` a private static member function, since it's part of `Foo`'s internals.

If `notMethod` was an operator that needs to take a non-`Foo` as its first argument (meaning that it can't be a member of `Foo`), and if I wanted to keep `Bar` private, I would make the operator a friend.

If `notMethod` implements a generic operation on iterators, I would make it a template function.

If `Bar` is a class that might be of interest to `Foo`'s clients, I would make `Bar` and the typedef public and use the solution I suggested originally.

Comment: Yup, this works... doesn't the public typedef expose class Bar to some degree though?

Comment: That's correct. I'll edit the answer to discuss what your alternatives are to making the typedef public.

Comment: @suszterpatt: If you truly want any non-method (such as `notMethod()`) to be able to take this iterator parameter, then logically you *should* expose the typedef (and thus `Bar`). If you don't want "any old" non-method to be able to take such a parameter, then use one of Martin's other alternatives. As one more alternative, you could make all `Bar`'s members private and declare `Foo` to be a friend of `Bar`.

Answer (score 4):

[Friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2x4fzdz(VS.80).aspx).

Add

```
friend void notMethod(mapType::iterator it);
```

to your Foo class and you can keep your inner classes and functions private.

Comment: Don't you think that declaring something as friend in this case is an overkill?

Comment: No.  It is better than making the internal private class public.

Comment: This doesn't work as you posted it originally, but changing `mapType` to `Foo::mapType` everywhere in `notMethod` is all you need to get it working. :)

Also, @orsogufo: why do you think a friend function is overkill?

Comment: Sorry, I had really misunderstood the question :( Please ignore my previous comment...

Answer (score 4):

Building upon Martin B's answer:

The reason *notMethod* doesnt know the type *mapType* is because it is inside the class *Foo*, you can think of classes as *namespaces* in this case if you want.

Either way, you must change the code to:

```
void notMethod(Foo::mapType::iterator it) {}
```

If you agree with Martin B, you must move the typedef to the *public* section of the class. If you agree with DanDan you must [Friend](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/friend) the function.

Myself? I would put the typedef outside the class, and put both the class and the typedef into a [namespace](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/namespace).

Comment: From what I can tell, `notMethod()` is not inside the class `Foo`.

Comment: Correct, it is not. However, the typedef mapType is. Compare the placement of Foo:: in method() and (in the corrected) notMethod().

Answer (score 3):

[Martin B has provided you with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328496/is-there-a-way-to-typedef-this/1328513#1328513#). Here's an alternative:

Your `notMethod()` looks like some implementation detail to me, that's likely defined in the cpp file's unnamed namespace. What I usually do in this case is to make `notMethod()` a template:

```
template< typename It >
void notMethod(It it) {
    // ...
}
```

Besides avoiding to make the `typedef` public or making the function a friend, this has the added benefit that, should the function provide a useful algorithm, you can invoke it with other iterators, too.